# Match any characters but not the string ... in sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to remove strings surrounded by other strings (`\[` and `\]`) in sed. I can match the start string `\[` easily, but after that I wan't to match any characters including `\` and `]` but not if they are in a row (`\]` end string).

Is that possible ?

Comment: please add sample input and output for testing and clarity...

Comment: @Sundeep, here's what I'm trying to do with this : s=`echo $PS1 | sed ...`. Then by removing every unprintable characters (contained between `\[` and `\]`). I am able to count the length of `$PS1`. I'm doing this with something that will be part of `$PS1`, not `$PS1` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -e 's/\\\[\([^\\]\|\\[^]]\)*\\\]//g'`

Anatomy of the search pattern:

```
\\\[             starting delimiter
    \(
      [^\\]      not a backslash
           \|    or
      \\[^]]     a backslash followed by any char except a right bracket
    \)*          repeat as many times as possible
\\\]             ending delimiter
```

Comment: Well thanks, that seams to work! But there is an error when run inside subshell ? Weird ? (inside backticks or `$(...)`). Simple example: ``x= `echo stuff | sed -e 's/\\\[\([^\\]\|\\[^]]\)*\\\]//g' ` ``

Comment: Backticks are weird. They eat backslashes. The preferred syntax is `$(...)`. Use `x="$(echo stuff | sed -e 's/\\\[\([^\\]\|\\[^]]\)*\\\]//g')"`.